# Pending suggested edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, user-interface, notifications

Since the new user interface was put in place, a notification was added so that users would know when there is more then five suggested edits in the edit queue.  This icon has always displayed in a lighter orange color (which I do not have a picture of at the moment).

Then today, I was browsing and I noticed the notification was a shade of red?

[image]

I'm assuming the different colors mean different things, but is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Ah that post did not turn up when I was searching for previous questions!